# Clear the last element from a linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

I am working on a C program which has a linked list. I need to remove the last element from the linked list and it is mostly working except when it hits particular part of my code it then has a segmentation fault.

The code that I have is as follows:

```
int clearOutboundLegFromList(callLogSearchOutboundStruct ** outboundLeg, int dataCol, int rowTargets)
{
    //callLogSearchOutboundStruct *currentStruct = *outboundLeg;
    //callLogSearchOutboundStruct *temp;
    if (*outboundLeg == NULL)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    SL_DebugAll(DBG_ALWAYS, "DEBUG: Clearing outbound legs: DataCol: %i RowTargets: %i",
            dataCol, rowTargets);
    callLogSearchOutboundStruct *legToRemove = NULL;
    callLogSearchOutboundStruct *last = NULL;
    legToRemove = *outboundLeg;

    while (legToRemove->nextLeg != NULL)
    {
        last = legToRemove;
        legToRemove = legToRemove->nextLeg;
    }
    if (legToRemove->target != NULL)
    {
        free(legToRemove->target);
        legToRemove->target = NULL;
    }
    if (legToRemove->cleardownCause)
    {
        free(legToRemove->cleardownCause);
        legToRemove->cleardownCause = NULL;
    }

    free(legToRemove);

    if (last != NULL)
    {
        last->nextLeg = NULL;
    }
    legToRemove = NULL;
}
```

It crashes on the line of `free(legToRemove->target);`.

In the core dump I have the following:

```
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x00b01336 in _int_free () from /lib/libc.so.6
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install cyrus-sasl-lib-2.1.23-13.el6_3.1.i686 glibc-2.12-1.132.el6_5.2.i686 keyutils-libs-1.4-4.el6.i686 krb5-libs-1.10.3-15.el6_5.1.i686 libcom_err-1.41.12-18.el6.i686 libcurl-7.19.7-37.el6_5.3.i686 libidn-1.18-2.el6.i686 libselinux-2.0.94-5.3.el6_4.1.i686 libssh2-1.4.2-1.el6.i686 mysql-libs-5.1.73-3.el6_5.i686 nspr-4.9.2-1.el6.i686 nss-3.14.0.0-12.el6.i686 nss-softokn-freebl-3.12.9-11.el6.i686 nss-util-3.14.0.0-2.el6.i686 openldap-2.4.23-31.el6.i686 openssl-1.0.1e-16.el6_5.14.i686 zlib-1.2.3-29.el6.i686
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00b01336 in _int_free () from /lib/libc.so.6
#1  0x0805cd0b in clearOutboundLegFromList (outboundLeg=0xb5de7984, dataCol=9, rowTargets=11) at performreport.c:6731
#2  0x08058f33 in processDrilldownData (reportParameterArray=..., csvFile=0x8e3fc78, HandleDB=0xbfca7a14, resultReport=0x8e457a8,
```

If I print from the core dump legToRemove->target gdb outputs the following:

```
$1 = 0x99235d8 ""
```

Now that looks like its a properly allocated memory space, it just contains an empty string so I don't understand why this would cause a segfault.

Comment: You don't give enough information to find the real cause. But here are two possible causes: The `target` field must be allocated with `malloc` if you want to `free` it. Either you haven't done that (because `target` is a char array in the struct, say `target[20]`, or because it is just a pointer to some other memory) or you have altered the value of `target` after allocating it.

Comment: i'm not sure about if (legToRemove->cleardownCause), why not if (NULL != legToRemove->cleardownCause)

Comment: What is the purpose of the function arguments `, int dataCol, int rowTargets)`. They appear to be unused. Are they intended to identify the element to be deleted?

Comment: The memory for the string is strdup'ed for the target. Regarding the arguments, the function was originally written a different way and then realised they weren't needed, so yes, at the moment they are unused

Comment: Okay, if the memory comes from `strdup`, `free` should work okay.

Comment: When `last` is null, you should probably update your head pointer `outboundLeg`, which you have already passed by reference, but which you never update. This might be the cause of the corrupt `free`: After removing the second but last node in the list, you access the invalidated memory of the old head node.

Comment: @MOehm I'm not to see so now how I would do that. I'm quite new to C so still learning it as I go along. From the code I have I thought it would be updating the linkedlist from the passed in pointer reference so I wouldn't need to explicitly update it as the code is updating the passed in pointer

Comment: I'll prepare an answer; an explanation will be too long for a comment.

Comment: I wonder why your code was crashing in `free()` and not _much_ earlier. IMHO it should never even get close to `free()`... Just in the beginning, after some debug action the function does: `callLogSearchOutboundStruct *legToRemove = NULL; /*...*/ while (legToRemove->nextLeg != NULL) {...}` which is dereferencing a `NULL` pointer. I'm curious why didn't it crash right here???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't show how your struct looks like or how you add legs to your linked list, but you have an error in your removal function that occurs if you remove the last node: In that case, your list head should be set to `NULL`.

This special case is the reason to pass the list head as pointer to pointer to leg: The function must be able to update the head when the first node is removed. If you don't do that, the value of the head in the calling function will be the same and it will refer to memory that you have just `free`d. It is illegal to access such memory.

So, an updated version of your code could look like this:

```
void clearOutboundLegFromList(callLogSearchOutboundStruct **outboundLeg)
{
    callLogSearchOutboundStruct *last = NULL;
    legToRemove = *outboundLeg;

    if (legToRemove == NULL) return;

    while (legToRemove->nextLeg) {
        last = legToRemove;
        legToRemove = legToRemove->nextLeg;
    }

    free(legToRemove->target);
    free(legToRemove->cleardownCause);
    free(legToRemove);

    if (last) {
        last->nextLeg = NULL;
    } else {
        *outboundLeg = NULL;        
    }
}
```

You need the explicit assignment at the end, because once you have initialised `legToRemove`, you are operating only with that local pointer.

If you are feeling more confident with double indirections via pointers to pointers, you could iterate to the end without local variabes:

```
void clearOutboundLegFromList(callLogSearchOutboundStruct **outboundLeg)
{
    if (*outboundLeg == NULL) return;

    while (*outboundLeg) {
        outboundLeg = &(*outboundLeg)->nextLeg;
    }

    free((*outboundLeg)->target);
    free((*outboundLeg)->cleardownCause);
    free(*outboundLeg);

    *outboundLeg = NULL;        
}
```

This will update the head pointer automatically when the first element is removed. The idea here ist that `outboundLeg` points to the head node at the beginning and to the previous node's `nextLeg` pointer on subsequent iterations. The additional indirection via `(*outboundLeg)` is more or less the same as accessing a node via the `nextLeg` member, except for the first node, in which you access the pointer through the head node pointer.

(Distraction: Your code is overly cautious when freeing the member pointers. It is legal to `free` a null pointer; this doesn't do anything, but means that you don't have to check for `NULL` in client code. Such a check might still be good practice, because many functions won't take null pointers. Setting the member pointers to `NULL` is a good idea if these pointers were still around for some time. But you are going to `free` the containing struct anyway soon. Setting the pointers to `NULL` is a bit like cleaning the bathroom just before you tear down the house. Setting `legToRemove` to `NULL` at the end of the function doesn't do anything: The pointer will go out of scope anyway. That's just an aside and retionale for my shorter code. Your checks aren't wrong and it is better to be cautious.)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer very helpful. I went for the first option of doing *outboundLeg = NULL and this seems to have resolved the problem.